# Validação de Campo em html e php

Tags: php, email, validação

Gostaria de uma ajuda para validar um campo no formulario para verificar se ja há um mesmo email que o usuário digitar no banco de dados. Quando o usuario clicar no botao "cadastrar" ira enviar direto para a pagina "enviaCadastro.php" sem nenhuma validação a nao ser do proprio bootstrap. Não sei se eu valido o campo email no proprio cadastro.php ou no enviaCadastro.php. Estou usando o PHP  PDO para cadastro no banco de dados.

**cadastro.php**

```
    <form action="enviaCadastro.php" method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
          <div class="col-md mb-3">    
                  <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" maxlength="30" required >
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">Preencha com um e-mail</div><br>
          </div>
    </form>
```

**enviaCadastro.php**

session_start();
   include_once 'conectaBanco.php';

$clicaCadastro = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'clicaCadastro', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

```
if($clicaCadastro){
    //Pega os dados do form
    $nome = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sobrenome = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'sobrenome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $datanasc = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'datanasc', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $genero = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'genero', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $estado = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'estado', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $cidade = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'cidade', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $senha = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //insere no banco de dados
    $envia = "INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sobrenome, nasc, genero, estado, cidade, email, senha) VALUES (:nome, :sobrenome, :datanasc, :genero, :estado, :cidade, :email, :senha)";

    $insere_bd = $conecta->prepare($envia);
    $insere_bd ->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
    $insere_bd ->bindParam(':sobrenome', $sobrenome);
    $insere_bd ->bindParam(':datanasc', $datanasc);
    $insere_bd ->bindParam(':genero', $genero);
    $insere_bd ->bindParam(':estado', $estado);
    $insere_bd ->bindParam(':cidade', $cidade);
    $insere_bd ->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $insere_bd ->bindParam(':senha', $senha);

    if($insere_bd->execute()){
        header("Location: cadastroRealizado.php");
    }else{
        header("Location: cadastroErro.php");
    }


}else{
    $_SESSION ['erro'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Cadastro nao efetuado</p>";
    echo "erro ao cadastrar";

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Creio que está função possa ajuda-lo:

```
    public static function EmailValidate(string $val) : bool
    {
        return (bool)filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    }
```

Essa é uma das funções de minha classe de validações:
https://github.com/hax0rlib/xSecurity

Comment: no caso essa validação ja existe, eu queria uma que verifique se já há um e-mail cadastrado no banco de dados de acordo com o e-mail que o usuário colocar.

Answer (score -1):

Da mesma maneira que você criou a query de insert você cria uma que realiza o select ,a estrutura usando PDO fica nessa esquema:

```
  $sql = ("SELECT id FROM cadastro WHERE email=:email");
        $teste = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $teste->bindParam(":email", $email);
        $teste->execute();
        $has = $teste->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        //Caso $has seja diferente de nulo significa que o email já existe.
```